# Issues while processing zeroes found in CSV input file with Perl

Tags: regex, shell, csv, perl, awk

Friends:

I have to process a CSV file, using Perl language and produce an Excel as output, using the Excel::Writer::XSLX module. This is not a homework but a real life problem, where I cannot download whichever Perl version (actually, I need to use Perl 5.6), or whichever Perl module (I have a limited set of them). My OS is UNIX. I can also use (embedding in Perl) ksh and csh (with some limitation, as I have found so far). Please, limit your answers to the tools I have available. Thanks in advance!

Even though I am not a Perl developer, but coming from other languages, I have already done my work. However, the customer is asking for extra processing where I am getting stuck on.

1) The stones in the road I found are coming from two sides: from Perl and from Excel particular styles of processing data. I already found a workaround to handle the Excel, but -as mentioned in the subject- I have difficulties while processing zeroes found in CSV input file. To handle the Excel, I am using the `'0` way which is the final way for data representation that Excel seems to have while using the `@` formatting style.

2) Scenario:

I need to catch standalone zeroes which might be present in whichever line / column / cell of the CSV input file and put them as such (as zeroes) in the Excel output file.

I will go directly to the point of my question to avoid loosing your valuable time. I am providing more details after my question:

Research and question:

- I tried to use Perl regex to find standalone "0" and replace them by whichever string, planning to replace them back to "0" at the end of processing.

```sh
perl -p -i -e 's/\b0\b/string/g' myfile.csv`
```

and

```sh
perl -i -ple 's/\b0\b/string/g'  myfile.csv
```

Are working; but only from command line. They aren't working when I call them from the Perl script as follows:

```
system("perl -i -ple 's/\b0\b/string/g' myfile.csv")
```

Do not know why... I have already tried using `exec` and `eval`, instead of `system`, with the same results.

Note that I have a ton of regex that work perfectly with the same structure, such as the following:

```
system("perl -i -ple 's/input/output/g' myfile.csv")
```

I have also tried using backticks and `qx//`, without success. Note that `qx//` and backticks have not the same behavior, since `qx//` is complaining about the boundaries \b because of the forward slash.

I have tried using `sed -i`, but my System is rejecting `-i` as invalid flag (do not know if this happens in all UNIX, but at least happens in the one at work. However is accepting `perl -i`).

I have tried embedding `awk` (which is working from command line), in this way:

```
system `awk -F ',' -v OFS=','  '$1 == \"0\" { $1 = "string" }1' myfile.csv > myfile_copy.csv
```

But this works only for the first column (in command line) and, other than having the disadvantage of having extra copy file, Perl is complaining for `>` redirection, assuming it as "greater than"...

```
system(q@awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";split("1 2 3 4 5",A," ") } { for(i in A)sub(0,"string",$A[i] ) }1' myfile.csv@);
```

This `awk` is working from command line, but only 5 columns. But not in Perl using `@`.

All the combinations of `exec` and `eval` have also been tested without success.

I have also tried passing to `system` each one of the `awk` components, as arguments, separated by commas, but did not find any valid way to pass the redirector (`>`), since Perl is rejecting it because of the mentioned reason.

Using another approach, I noticed that the "standalone zeroes" seem to be "swallowed" by the Text::CSV module, thus, I get rid off it, and turned back to a traditional looping in csv line by line and a spliter for commas, preserving the zeroes in that way. However I found the "mystery" of `isdual` in Perl, and because of the limitation of modules I have, I cannot use the `Dumper`. Then, I also explored the guts of binaries in Perl and tried the `$x ^ $x`, which was deprecated since version 5.22 but valid till that version (I said mine is 5.6). This is useful to catch numbers vs strings. However, while `if( $x ^ $x )` returns `TRUE` for strings, `if( !( $x ^ $x ) )` does not returns `TRUE` when `$x = 0`. [UPDATE: I tried this in a devoted Perl script, just for this purpose, and it is working. I believe that my probable wrong conclusion ("not returning TRUE") was obtained when I did not still realize that Text::CSV was swallowing my zeroes. Doing new tests...].

**I will appreciate very much your help!**

**MORE DETAILS ON MY REQUIREMENTS:**

1) This is a dynamic report coming from a database which is handover to me and I pickup programmatically from a folder. Dynamic means that it might have whichever amount of tables, whichever amount of columns in each table, whichever names as column headers, whichever amount of rows in each table.

2) I do not know, and cannot know, the column names, because they vary from report to report. So, I cannot be guided by column names.

A sample input:

```
Alfa,Alfa1,Beta,Gamma,Delta,Delta1,Epsilon,Dseta,Heta,Zeta,Iota,Kappa
0,J5,alfa,0,111.33,124.45,0,0,456.85,234.56,798.43,330000.00
M1,0,X888,ZZ,222.44,111.33,12.24,45.67,0,234.56,0,975.33
```

3) Input Explanation

a) This is an example of a random report with 12 columns and 3 rows. Fist row is header.

b) I call "standalone zeroes" those "clean" zeroes which are coming in the CSV file, from second row onwards, between commas, like `0,` (if the case is the first position in the row) or like `,0,` in subsequent positions.

c) In the second row of the example you can read, from the beginning of the row: `0,J5,alfa,0`, which in this particular case, are "words" or "strings". In this case, 4 names (note that two of them are zeroes, which required to be treated as *strings*). Thus, we have a 4 names-columns example (`Alfa,Alfa1,Beta,Gamma` are headers for those columns, but only in this scenario). From that point onwards, in the second row, you can see floating point (*.00) numbers and, among them, you can see 2 zeroes, which are *numbers*. Finally, in the third line, you can read `M1,0,X888,Z`, which are the names for the first 4 columns. Note, please, that the 4th column in the second row has `0` as name, while the 4th column in the third row has `ZZ` as name.

Summary: as a general picture, I have a table-report divided in 2 parts, from left to right: 4 columns for names, and 8 columns for numbers.
Always the first M columns are names and the last N columns are numbers.
- It is unknown which number is M: which amount of columns devoted for words / strings I will receive.
- It is unknown which number is N: which amount of columns devoted for numbers I will receive.
- It is KNOWN that, after the M amount of columns ends, always starts N, and this is constant for all the rows.

Comment: `"...\b..."` should be `"...\\b..."` to produce the string `...\b...`. (But why are you launching `perl` from a Perl program?)

Comment: You might have more people willing to read your question if you can reduce it a lot to just the basics (I want to do A, I tried B, it failed because of C, here's my sample input D and expected output E) Relatively view people will have the time or enthusiasm to read through everything you've currently posted to try to help you.

Comment: `system \`...\`` doesn't make much sense. Backticks execute the command the return the output, which you then pass to `system` to execute as command.

Comment: Backticks act as double-quoted string literals. Just like you needed to escape `\ ` to produce a literal `\ ` as mentioned above, you need to escape `$`

Comment: Re "*I noticed that the "standalone zeroes" seem to be "swallowed" by the Text::CSV module*", That is not the case. A field as of `0` will be returned as-is.

Comment: I agree that `\b` inside `"..."` is the problem since that would just be `b` since `\ ` is the escape char inside `"..."`. Instead of `"...\\b..."` use could also try `system( q( perl -i -ple 's/\b0\b/string/g' myfile.csv ) )` since `q(...)` is the same as `'...'` except it allows the use of `'` inside the string. The difference between `"..."` and `'...'` is that the former interpolates variables and have \ escapes while the latter doesn't.

Comment: @EdMorton: You are right. I considered it while writing my question. That is why I "tried" to put the elemental things at the beginning, followed by my question, and after that, I added "MORE DETAILS...".

Comment: Thanks to all of you who helped me! I am reading all your valuable comments!

Answer (score 1):

I have done a quick research on Perl boundaries for regex ( `\b` ), and I have not found any relevant information regarding if it applies or not in Perl 5.6.

However, since you are using and old Perl version, try the traditional UNIX / Linux style (I mean, what Perl inherits from Shell), like this:

`system("perl -i -ple 's/^0/string/g' myfile.csv");`

The previous regex should do the work doing the change at the start of the each line in your CSV file, if matches.

Or, maybe better (if you have those "standalone" zeroes, and want avoid any unwanted change in some "leading zeroes" string):

`system("perl -i -ple 's/^0,/string,/g' myfile.csv");`

[Note that I have added the comma, after the zero; and, of course, after the string].

Note that the first regex should work; the second one is just a "caveat", to be cautious.

Comment: Great, Pablo! Thanks so much! Both solutions worked! +1 for you!